# How to test a newly created /etc/init/XX.conf file?

Tags: boot

I created a /etc/init/XX.conf file , but don't know how to test it.

It's now like stuff stored in /etc/init.d , which can use `service` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start XX

stop XX

Take a look at upstart manual.